# I'm getting a constant 'error' used before being initialized message

Tags: swift

I'm having and error come up now that claims  constant 'error' used before being initialized.  I thought that is what I was doing by saying let e = error.

```
   let error: NSError?

   if let e = error {
        print(e.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        recorder.prepareToRecord()
        recorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
    }
```

hmm.  Unsure what that is all about.

-sorry about that guys.  here is the extra code....

//declare a variable to store the returned error if we have a problem instantiating our AVAudioRecorder

```
      let error: NSError?

    //Instantiate an AVAudioRecorder
    recorder = try? AVAudioRecorder(url: url, settings: recordSettings as! [String : AnyObject])

    //If there's an error, print otherwise, run prepareToRecord and meteringEnabled to turn on metering (must be run in that order)
    if let e = error {
       print(e.localizedDescription)
      } else {
        recorder.prepareToRecord()
        recorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
```

Comment: You need to initialise `error` before using it – optional constants aren't automatically initialised to `nil` (as that wouldn't be useful at all).

Comment: Don't post code in comments. [Edit] your question.

Comment: sorry guys.  Updated question......

Comment: @leodabus What 2 characters were added?  I can't see what was added.